# How to divide data into chunks where the first chunk is large but the rest of data divided as equally same size of chunks?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to split the data into chunks where the first chunk is large and then comes the rest of the data after taking the first chunk which is divided into equal sizes of chunks
here is my code:

```
def chunk_data(dataset, size=10):
    if size > len(dataset):
          raise TypeError("size must be less than length of dataset")

    rest = []
    half_size = size // 2
    first_chunk = dataset[: half_size]
    rest_data = len(dataset) - len(first_chunk)
    num_chunks = rest_data // half_size

    for i in range(num_chunks):
          rest.append(dataset[i * half_size:(i + 1) * half_size])
    return rest
```

how can I modify it to do this

Comment: You can use `numpy.split` for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `rest_data variable` then can apply `numpy.array_split()`. You can then merge first large chunk with the rest as follows:

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np

def chunk_data(dataset, chunk_counts=10):
    len_dataset = len(dataset)
    if chunk_counts > len_dataset:
        raise TypeError("chunk_counts must be less than length of dataset")

    half_size = len_dataset // 2
    first_chunk = [dataset[: half_size].tolist()]
    rest_data = dataset[half_size:]
    rest_chunks_np = np.array_split(rest_data, chunk_counts-1)
    rest_chunks = [arr.tolist() for arr in rest_chunks_np]
    return first_chunk + rest_chunks

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.random.randint(2, size=1000)
    chunks = chunk_data(data)
    print(f"[main] # chunks: {len(chunks)}")
    for chunk_id, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        print(f"[main] # items in chunk-{chunk_id}: {len(chunk)}")
```

**Result:**

```
[main] # chunks: 10
[main] # items in chunk-0: 500
[main] # items in chunk-1: 56
[main] # items in chunk-2: 56
[main] # items in chunk-3: 56
[main] # items in chunk-4: 56
[main] # items in chunk-5: 56
[main] # items in chunk-6: 55
[main] # items in chunk-7: 55
[main] # items in chunk-8: 55
[main] # items in chunk-9: 55
```

Comment: can I have the output first_chunk + rest_chunks as an array ? I'm doing np.array of it but it's not working

Comment: @user4556432 the index notation for the first_chunk is `chunks[0]` and the slice notation for the rest_chunks is `chunks[1:]`. In addition, the array you asked is `chunks`.

Comment: but it's giveing the output : 
[[-1.0, -1.0], [-2.0, -1.9], [-3.0, -2.0], [1.0, 1.5]]
[[2.7, 1.0], [3.0, 2.0], [-4.0, 10.0]]
[[-10.0, 5.0], [-6.0, -10.0]]
as nested list, how can I make it an array

Comment: ]
as nested list, how can I make it an array? then combine them again together?

Comment: @user4556432 What is your definition of an array in your question in comment? The definition of a formal array is a data structure, which store a fixed-size collection of elements of the same data type. I thought that the array means a list (informal) in your question. In your question, you asked `the first chunk is large and then comes the rest of the data after taking the first chunk`. I exactly implemented what you asked. You should provide an exemplary input, and expected outputs in your question and modify your problem description if you want different results.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can use `np.split()` for this:

```py
x = np.random.randint(0, 9, (12, 5))

num_chunks = 3
first_half, second_half = np.split(x, 2)
chunks = np.split(second_half, num_chunks)
```

If you don't want the first partition to be exactly half, then use slicing:

```py
n = 8  # size of largest chunk

large_chunk = x[:n]
small_chunks = np.split(x[n:], num_chunks)
```